# UIImageView memory usage

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

When animating a number of frames using UIImageView how does iOS map them into memory, is it simply image resolution x bit depth (i.e. a 200x200 24bit TGA will be the same as a 200x200 24bit JPG) or does iOS take into account unused alpha pixels in the image. Also how does this work with images loaded into the Xcode project (and maybe not used) and those that are directly loaded into memory (i.e. using UIImage imageNamed: from within the app)?

Comment: You can monitor memory consumption with Instruments, and setting up a test case to monitor should be straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, I will do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that even if the image is 24 bit it will decompress to 32bit, because the default color space is 4channels, the size usually is the `number_of_pixel_in_row*number_of_pixel_in_height*byte_for_pixels`. In my tests I always saw the same memory consumption even for different formats. Images are loaded lazily at the time they need to be drawn in a context, after that if not released they keep the memory pressure.That means that even if you create an UIImage object it won't be decompressed until it needs to be drawn . Methods such as -imageNamed caches the images in memory, I usually use it only for repetitive images. 
Hope this helps

Comment: You are welcome.Probably you find interesting also this ample code from Apple there are a lot of comments inside explaining image rendering in iOS [LargeImageDownsizing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html)